# AES 256 data encryption on Mysql

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt the whole data of a mysql DB using the AES 256 symmetric encryption method without encrypting the data manually using [AES_ENCRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) ?

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains about the same functionality in MsSql databases

Comment: Encrypt the hard drive?

Comment: Hmm... I prefer encrypting the data of the db and not the whole HD if it's possible

Comment: You could store the MySQL database on a separate partition and encrypt only that partition.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - but, encrypting the partition itself helps only if someone tries to read the data without being already logged to the OS.. right?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support data file encryption natively, but there are ways to do it.
There is a product called Vormetric Transparent Encryption. Read info about it here: http://www.vormetric.com/data-security-solutions/use-cases/database-encryption
But if you want to actually use SQL for this purpose, newer versions support AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() (the official AES standard).
You can read about the two functions here, in the mysql 5.x manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

So basically you can encrypt the data prior to the insert query. MySql wont know the difference. also, you will have to decrypt it when extracting any data.

Answer (score 1):

[XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/encrypted_backups_innobackupex.html) provides such a functionality

Comment: sounds interesting. is it possible for live db and not only for backups?

Comment: I think you are looking for filesystem encryption.

Comment: I just found this presentation, pls read slide 53 and following: http://www.yassl.com/files/yassl_securing_mysql.pdf